# Another complex MySQL query involving combinations

Tags: mysql, join, combinations

Lets say we have a table that looks like this

```
connection_requirements
+-----------------------------------+ 
| item_id | connector_id | quantity | 
+---------+--------------+----------+ 
| 1       | 4            | 1        | 
| 1       | 5            | 1        | 
| 1       | 2            | 2        | 
+---------+--------------+----------+
```

This table is a list of connectors that a electronic device requires to operate, and how many of each type of connector it requires. (Think connections on a motherboard requiring certain types of connectors from a power supply)

Now we also have this table...

```
connections_compatability 
+-------------------------+ 
| connector_id | works_as | 
+--------------+----------+ 
| 6            | 4        | 
| 6            | 5        | 
+--------------+----------+
```

Where the first column is the connector that can also act as the connector id of the second column. (For instance a power supply has connectors such as "6+2 Pin" which can work as "8 Pin" or "6 Pin")

Now finally we have how many of each connectors are available in this table

```
connector_quantities 
+-------------------------+ 
| connector_id | quantity | 
+--------------+----------+ 
| 1            | 1        | 
| 2            | 3        | 
| 3            | 2        | 
| 4            | 1        | 
| 5            | 0        | 
| 6            | 4        | 
| 7            | 0        | 
| 8            | 5        | 
+--------------+----------+
```

Based off these tables, as you can infer, we do have enough connectors for item number 1 to properly operate. Even though we do not have enough of connector #5, we have 4 connector #6s, which can work as connector #4 and #5.

The connection_requirements table is joined onto the items table, how can we filter items that require more connections than we have available? We already have the code in place to filter items that require connectors that are unavailable.

The problem has many more layers of complexity to it, so we tried to simplify the problem.

Much appreciation for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to determine the "real" inventory of items including their substitutions. E.g., the real inventory of part 4 is actually 5: 1-part #4 + 4-part #6. So using that:

```
Select ...
From connection_requirements As CR
Where Not Exists    (
                    Select 1
                    From connector_quantities As Q1
                        Left Join   (
                                    Select C2.connector_id, C2.works_as, Q2.quantity
                                    From connections_compatibility As C2
                                        Join connector_quantities As Q2
                                            On Q2.connector_id = C2.connector_id
                                    ) As Subs1
                            On Subs1.works_as = Q1.connector_id
                    Where Q1.connector_id = CR.connector_id
                        And ( Coalesce(Subs1.quantity, 0) + Q1.quantity ) > CR.quantity
                    )
```

There is of course a catch with this approach. Suppose you have an item with a makeup of: `4 #4 connectors and 2 #6 connectors`. Technically, you do have 4 #4 connectors (1 #4, and 3 #6 substitutions) but in combination with the requirement of 2 #6 connectors, you do not have enough parts. To solve this problem you would likely have to use a loop or multiple queries which would determine on-hand inventory after you use up all your primary parts.

Comment: Your indentation style is out of control. Esp. in SO where stuff scrolls out of view. Most unhelpful.

Comment: @Johan - What scrolling? The query doesn't scroll on my view. Obviously, indentation style is a personal preference, but IMO it makes it easier to separate the derived tables needed. Also, MySQL does not let me add an Inner Join to the Left Join such that the inner join is processed first. I.e., I have to use a derived table which adds indentation.

Comment: @Thomas, the scrolling depends on the browser settings. On my default setting it starts scolling pretty quickly.

Comment: @Johan - Interesting. I don't get scrolling in FF4 or IE9 but I do a tiny bit of scrolling Chrome and IE8. Not really a browser setting so much as the browser itself.

Comment: @Thomas, I have FF4, it depends on the zoom setting.

Comment: @Johan - I don't think so. No amount of zooming on my part (out or in) causes the display to scroll.

Comment: @Johan - Anyway. Interesting to know that I have less scroll space than I might think. Will consider it in the future.

Comment: @Thomas, I know so because I'm looking at it.

Comment: @Johan - There must be something else at play because I too am using FF4 and have no scrolling regardless of zoom. I don't doubt that you see scrolling, I'm just curious why I do not and you do.

Comment: The problem with this solution, is if the item requires one #4 and one #5 connector, and you only have 1 #6 available. The query will still return the item as being comparable, however because they are both checked in the same query, it will seem like there are enough connections. Any ideas?

Comment: @Evan Purkhiser - Wait. My bad. Yes, the scenario you discuss is the scenario I mention at the end of my post which is that your substitutes get exhausted across multiple items. Give me a few and I'll see if there might be a way around this problem which requires multiple queries.

Comment: @Evan Purkhiser - In looking at it closer, you need to run something recursively, Let's take an example, you have an item that requires 1 #4 and 1 #5 and you have 0 #4, 0 #5 and 1 #6 on hand. There is no way for the query to know that that you used the 1 #6 in place of the #4 instead of the #5. You need something that is decrementing inventory as it applies a connector to an item as opposed to the set of connectors for an item.